# "name is not defined" inside function inside condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, if-statement, tkinter

When I run the code below, and press the 'go' button, I get the error:

> NameError: name 'be' is not defined

...on the following line in the `countdown` function:

```
if be >= 0:
```

Even if I add `global be` in the function `countdown`, I get the same error.

```
import tkinter as tk

def set1():
    global be
    if be1 is not '':
        be = int(en.get())
    
def countdown():
    global be    
    if be >= 0:
        mins, secs = divmod(be, 60)
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)        
        label['text'] = timer
        root.after(1000, countdown)
        be -= 1


root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, text = '00:00', font = 'Helvetica 25')
label.pack()
en = tk.Entry(root)
en.pack()
be1 = en.get()
tk.Button(root, text = 'set', height = 3, width = 20, command = lambda: set1()).pack()
tk.Button(root, text = 'go', height = 3, width = 20, command = lambda: countdown()).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Why doesn't `global be` resolve the problem?

Comment: You never *call* the function, so it doesn't matter whether or not the `a` it assigns to is `global`.

Comment: `print()` returns `None`, by the way, so assigning it to a variable doesn't seem constructive

Comment: Is this example representative of your real code/issue? Otherwise, this seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/359870)?

Comment: Yep i created an xy problem I'll edit it

Answer (score 0):

The reason is clear from the error message: you need to define `be` as a global variable. Note that the `global` statement does not define the variable, it merely links the local references to that name with an *existing* global variable. But if it doesn't exist, there is nothing to match it with.

So you should define `be` as a global variable, like:

```
be = 0
```

There are a few other issues and things to improve:

- `be1` is read from the input only once, when the script starts, not when the user clicks a button. So its value will always remain the empty string. Instead, you should read the input into `be1` when the "set" button is clicked, and so the variable `be1` can just be a local variable in that `set1` function, not global as it is now.
- Don't use `is not` (or `is`) when comparing a variable with a string literal. So you should have:

  ```
  if be1 != '':
  ```
- It is better to already display the updated start-time when the user clicks the "set" button, even before the user clicks "go" -- otherwise they don't see the effect of clicking "set".
- Since you already have code for displaying the timer in the `countdown` function, it would be good to avoid code duplication and make a new function just for doing the displaying.

So taking all that together you would get:

```
import tkinter as tk

be = 0  # define as global here

def display():  # new function to avoid code repetition
    global be
    mins, secs = divmod(be, 60)
    timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
    label['text'] = timer

def set1():
    global be
    be1 = en.get()  # local variable, reading fresh input value
    if be1 != '':  # don't use "is not" with a literal
        be = int(be1)
        display()
    
def countdown():
    global be    
    if be >= 0:
        display()
        root.after(1000, countdown)
        be -= 1


root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, text = '00:00', font = 'Helvetica 25')
label.pack()
en = tk.Entry(root)
en.pack()
tk.Button(root, text = 'set', height = 3, width = 20, command = lambda: set1()).pack()
tk.Button(root, text = 'go', height = 3, width = 20, command = lambda: countdown()).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you give some feedback to this answer? Did it suit your needs?